# Why my counter in the variable is reset when the cycle starts again

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a point clouds on some images from my data. But when I try to create cycle that will change indexes of data massive elements, the calculation break off and repeat from the start point. I do not really understand, why my variable x after my saving in it the last number of data point that I use, cleansed.

Here is all my code, but the part with the problem (I think) at the bottom. Once again, I do not understand why my counter in the variable is reset when the cycle starts again. Please, help

```
df = pd.read_excel('sample_data1(dynamics).xlsx', delimiter="\t", na_values=['.'], low_memory=True)
columns_values = list(df.columns.values)

col_values_X_right = list(df['Point of Regard Right X [px]'])
col_values_Y_right = list(df['Point of Regard Right Y [px]'])
stimulus_name = list(df['Stimulus'])
time = list(df['RecordingTime [ms]'])
n = len(time)
number_of_separatores = 0

for i in range(len(col_values_X_right)):
    if col_values_X_right[i] == '-':
        number_of_separatores += 1


image1 = mpl.image.imread('5_01.png')
image2 = mpl.image.imread('i5_01.png')


x = 0

for j in range(number_of_separatores//2):
    image_plot1 = plt.imshow(image1)
    for i in range(len(col_values_X_right)):
        if stimulus_name[x+1] == '5_01.jpg' and col_values_X_right[x+1] != '-':
                plt.scatter([col_values_X_right[x+1]], [col_values_Y_right[x+1]])
                x += 1
        else:
            x += i   %I think that problem is here, but I don't know how to solve it  
            break
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you explain what your code is meant to do? Please provide a [mcve]. As an aside, why are you converting so many Series to lists?

Comment: @AMC For my university work, I try to create a programme that will make graph of eye gaze on the picture, that was stimulus material in the experiment. Since I don’t have access to the laboratory right now, I have to write everything myself. Usually, this kind of stuff exist in eye-trackers. 


What do you mean -- many series to lists? It is just experimental data: time, coordinates of gaze and info about stimulus material.

Comment: _What do you mean -- many series to lists?_ I was referring to all the `list(df['Point of Regard Right X [px]'])`, `list(df['Point of Regard Right Y [px]'])`, etc.

Comment: @AMC I don't know.. But how else I can store coordinates of the points?

Comment: _I don't know.. But how else I can store coordinates of the points?_ I'm not sure what you mean, I'm really just talking about the superfluous conversions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The break statement in the inner loop resets that loop's counter `i`, then you are adding that counter in the exception. The loop seems to be doing what is expected.

```
x = 0  
condition=True 
for j in range(10): 

    for i in range(7): #inner loop 
        if condition: 
            x +=1 
            if j > 2 and j < 5: 
                condition=False 

            print('outer: {:}, x: {:}, inner {:}, condition {:}'.format(
                j,x, i, condition)) 

        else:  
            x +=i 

            print('outer: {:}, x: {:}, inner {:}, condition {:}'.format(
                j,x, i, condition))
            break 

    if j == 5:
        condition = True
```

Comment: So.. again, what should I do, if I want this reset doesn't exist anymore? I am trying to understand your code like an example of this situation (where reset doesn't exist) but it is not clear for me...

Comment: Remove the break statement in the else (i.e. "exception") of the inner loop, then the inner loop will just run to 7 times for each time of the outer loop.

Comment: but in my situation, it will run not 7 times, but more than 10 000 times...

I found nonlocal function and global function, but I don't understand them yet. Maybe u can explain them to me, please? I think that I can use them here

Comment: maybe you can ask, another question? (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), with this code snippet, I simply shed light on "why your counter variable resets?"

Answer (score 1):

A quick tip.

This:

```py
for i in range(len(df['Point of Regard Right X [px]'])):
    if col_values_X_right[i] == '-':
        number_of_separatores += 1
```

can be simplified to:

```py
for elem in df['Point of Regard Right X [px]']:
    if elem == "-":
        number_of_separatores += 1
```

which can be further simplified to:

```py
number_of_separatores = df["Point of Regard Right X [px]"].eq("-").sum()
```

Comment: Thx, I am not really good with programming yet, but your ideas look really cool)